# ArcGIS 10.1 Model cannot be transferred between Win7 and Win8 machines

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, arcgis-desktop, windows-7, windows-8

[image: screenshot of attempt to "edit" model module]

We created a model (created in a file geodatabase) using Model Builder on a trial version of ArcGIS 10.1 (build 3035, License: Advanced). We are trying to now run it on a registered (build 3134, ArcMap 10.1, ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop SP1, License: Basic, ) version of ArcGIS 10.1 on another computer, but when we try to open it by right-clicking and selecting edit on the model it displays only the outlines of the tool-shapes within the model. We can't open the different modules of the model or anything to be edited. All the model does is calculate fields, so I was not expecting the basic license to be an issue. The same issue occurs when creating a model with the Basic registered version and trying to open it on the trial version, which leads me to think that this is an issue of transferring between computers, rather than a license-related issue. I changed the permissions on the .gdb folder to "full control" for everyone on the network to rule out permissions as an issue. The datasets in the model itself can be opened, but the actual tools (such as "Field calculate") are cannot be accessed. Could it be that the model is trying to reference, for example, the "field calculate" tool on the host computer with the wrong path??

Any ideas what the issue is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an error number? like Error 000816: the tool is not valid.

Comment: Was the trial version un-installed and standard installed?

Comment: Just to clarify, we composed the model on one computer (the trial ArcGIS 10.1) within a GDB  and are trying to run it on another computer (the basic ArcGIS 10.1 license), either off the LAN or by copying/pasting the entire GDB. The model is actually made up of nested models. There is no error message when I try to "edit" it. The shapes that constitute the model just show up as outlines (no colour within the shapes in most cases), and in some cases the lines do not match to form the squares they are supposed to form (ie. it looks like it's not displaying the graphics correctly).  thanks! ai.

Comment: PS. On the basic license computer, I can run different components of the model if I drag them from the Catalog window into a new Model Builder window, but I cannot open the different components for editing. I also cannot run the "super model" only sub-model parts. ai.

Comment: A screen shot would be helpful.

Comment: If its a model inside a fGDB, and you have "read-only" permissions on what looks like the folder of the GDB in Explorer, you wont be able to write/save edits. What happens if you make a new toolbox on disk, then copy the model from your fGDB toolbox to your disk based toolbox?

Comment: Thank you all!  @CurtisPrice: Tried to add a screenshot, but it seems you need a reputation score of 10 to add it!  @ KHibma:  I changed all permission to "Full Control" for "Everyone" (would that do the trick?) but same situation persists. Also, I tried to move modules to new toolbox on drive but same situation persists.

Comment: ***UPDATE: the model can be transferred from a Win7 machine to a Win7 Machine, but not from a Win7 machine to a Win8 machine. Not sure if it is in fact the OS that is the issue or something else that is installed on the Win8 machine. Anyone had any experience exporting a model between Win7 & Win8?

Comment: Perhaps your win8 machine is 64 bit vs 32 bit on win7?

Comment: @Johanvdw: They are both 64bit.

Comment: ***UPDATE*** tried running the model from Win8 on another Win8 machine -- it works! This means that the model can be transferred fine between two machines with the same platform (ie. Win7>>Win7 OR Win8>>Win8) but not between platforms.

Comment: I have to disagree with your above comment (see my answer to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60813/model-not-editable-on-a-different-pc/60894#60894)). On a daily basis I work with models syncing between my Win 8 Pro 64 bit and Win 7 Enterprise 64 bit computers, without an issue. Your comment is a blanket statement, when it should be "It appears that the model cannot be transferred between platforms" in your particular situation. If it works in a different scenario, then (theoretically) it should be able to work for other people as well.

Comment: @Arabella: agreed. Correction to the last update. It appears that the model cannot be transferred between platforms in my particular case. On another note, after trying to run the Win8_model_version on a Win8 account that was NOT the administrator on that machine, the same issue occurs. There's also the possibility that the issue is related to different permission settings between the Win7 and Win8 platforms. Tried running ArcGIS "as administrator" on the Win7 setup, but no luck. Arabella, can you please share what permission settings you are using on both machines?

Comment: The permissions could be the issue, as I have full admin rights on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 PCs.

Comment: @Arabella: Both accounts on both machines are administrators. I even tried running ArcGIS "as administrator" to see if that changes anything. Which version of Win7 are you using? Could it be that some hard-wired settings are set differently between different Win7 editions? We are running Win7 Home Edition.

Comment: I am on Win 7 Enterprise. At this point, all I can suggest is dragging in fresh copies of each tool and filling your inputs in again.

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but did you ever resolve this issue? / do you have any advice to share?

Comment: Sounds like it is time for you to use/learn Python for geoprocessing.

Comment: I'm having the same problem under 10.4.1
Has anybody a solution or workaround?
Running on Win7-64bit machines with admin-rights.

Answer (score 1):

Was ArcGIS for Desktop installed as Administrator?

Some other things to try:

1) Check that you have read/write on the Toolbox.
2) Try running ArcGIS as Administrator.
3) Turn off User Account Control (in the Control Panel > Users Accounts)

Good luck!