# ArcMap Model not editable on different PC

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, windows-8

I am using ArcMap 10.1 ModelBuilder on Windows 8 to create create models for my processes. But when I open the model using ArcMap 10.1 open model for editing with ArcMap 10.1 running on Windows 7 it appears not to be editable. I can run the model but I cannot edit it. When I open the model in ArcMap 10.1 running on windows 7 the model appears as on the screenshot attached below.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

I am yet to check if I will have the same problem when I try and edit the model on another Windows 8 platform.  The model does not use additional tool from extensions like "spatial analyst and so on..." it only uses data management tools.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes have a similar problem. Simply copy and pasting the contents of the whole model into a new model usually fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Take screenshots of your parameters inside each tool (or if you can memorise them, great). Drag in a fresh copy of each tool you used from ArcToolbox and delete the ones which are currently in your model. This happened to me alot when I initially was working between Windows 7 and 8, but now that I store my main toolbox on SkyDrive and sync between my home (Win 8) and work (Win 7) computers, I haven't had any problems like this anymore.