# Troubleshooting why ArcGIS Model works on one PC but not another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst

Do you have specific expertise you could share of examples where an ArcGIS Modelbuilder has worked on one PC but not on another?

Are there any issues between different Windows versions?

There is a related question here [ArcMap Model not editable on different PC](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60813/model-not-editable-on-a-different-pc)

In my example I have a model that runs to completion on a Windows 8 machine. I run the models from an external hard drive. When the same model is run from the same external drive but on a different PC - Windows 7 then the model crashes.

The model can be opened, edited and verified on both Pc's.

It just crashes on one but not the other.

I have explored possible options:

- ArcGIS Version and service packs - both are 10.1 SP1.
- RAM - the PC on which the models work has LESS RAM than the PC on which the models crash
- OS type - both machines are 64 bit.
- Model build - I have re-built the model by copying and pasting into new / clean models (I did this on the Windows 8 PC though)

I am not sure that the cause is the different Windows version, it is just the main difference I can see between the two PC's

I am using ArcMap 10.1 SP1 Advanced.

I have followed all the advice in setting up a shared Toolkit so all folder structure to Scratch, working directory, etc is set to named folders within the Toolkit. So I do not think that was the issue.

Unfortunately at the moment I do not have copies of crash report, etc to post here.

I have reported this issue to Esri, and sent them the relevant models but they were not able to reproduce the issue.

Ultimately, we upgraded our machines to 10.2.2 and we have not had the issue, although the models have been further edited a lot since that time.

I can only assume that it was some issue with 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

1) I would suggest that could drive structure / permissions. For example, a working directory is set that exists in the 8 folder structure but not 7. Not inputs or outputs but working or scratch.

2) As above but more likely a user profile structure that is different.

3) Check the error report as this likely tells you what is the exact cause (Geoprocessing > Results)

4) Rebuild just the process it fails on.

5) But my guess is an environment setting on 7 as opposed to 8.

6) Check build numbers (they can differ slightly even if SP is the same).

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this one, where you have already been able to package your data and model to transport it another machine for testing, my recommendation would be to consider contacting [Esri Support](http://support.esri.com) and offering to send them the package.

This is because they should be able to:

- test the same package on a range of configurations to look for a pattern of where it works, and where it does not; and/or
- submit it to the developers responsible for ModelBuilder to undertake detailed analysis, perhaps by inserting additional troubleshooting code.

---

I just noticed that your question has been updated to say that upgrading to ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop appeared to resolve this for you, and that Esri technical support were unable to reproduce your problem at 10.1.  Nevertheless, I'll leave my answer here because I think it offers an alternative to your own onsite testing and troubleshooting when a model you have invested time to develop (and troubleshoot) runs in one supported configuration but fails in another.